# Changing default printer in chrome by website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, printing

I have been looking all morning on how (or if it's even possible) to change the default printer in chrome for only one website.

I have to do this, because the site we build uses a label printer and the client does not want to change its default printer nor does he want to select the label printer everytime he has to print on the website.

The ways I have tought of are:

1- Adding an extension that would allow me to choose the default printer for a specific website.

2- Changing the select printer in print preview with javascript/jquery

I did not have any success with both. I don't think it's useful to say, but the website is in php.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked around talked with a few people in field and since I did not get an answer, I'll answer to myself:

Sadly it's impossible to do easily.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but I recently figured out how to do this for my business. I need to print labels from the stamps.com website, but don't want to keep swapping the default printer. Like you found, it appears it isn't possible to seamlessly set printer defaults on a per website basis in Chrome. What you can do however is create a second chrome profile (Click profile icon in upper right, then "add person") This will let you open a second browser instance, with it's own presets and defaults. Maybe not quite what your customer had in mind, but works well for me. (copy customer address from main browser, alt-tab to switch to second window, paste address and print label.)